# Re-using a knockoutJS 2 component within an Angular 2 TS component

Tags: angular, knockout-2.0

I'm in the process of migrating a project over to Angular2 w/ Typescript that was previously written in KnockoutJS. This turning out to be quite cumbersome to do, so I'd like to simply re-use some of the components I have written with KO inside of my Angular2 ones but I trouble finding an example of if this is possible.

My code would look something like as follows:

myKOComponent.js

```
returns {viewModel: myViewModel, template:myTemplate}
```

myAngularComponent.ts

```
//Here I want to import myKOComponent which there are 2 things I am unsure about
```

1. How do you import a component and then reference the object is returns.
2. The pattern I've been using is the parent (ie myAngularComponent) would append the template to an element and then call ko.applyBinding(new myViewModel, myTemplate), is this possible?

Thank-you for your time!

Comment: Angular 2 should automatically integrate with Knockout. Any click handler or DOM event handler will trigger the update of the Angular view. Did you run into a specific difficulty?

Comment: Its great to hear it should integrate. My question is related to the actual implementation of the integration, I am unsure of how you should do so. IE How do I import the KO component into the Angular Component and use it. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem as well. HOW to declare import statement for knockout or other thirdparty js that I npm install.

Comment: @cjr Hello, have you found a solution to this problem? I am looking for somewhat the same solution :) Any updates on this yet?

Comment: @stckvflw I didn't get far with this approach. I ended up re-writing everything in Angular, which to be honest was easier to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something I've actually tried, but perhaps something like this would work

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular/core';
import {MyViewModel} from './some-location';

declare var ko:any;

@Component{...}

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you import knockout TGH?

Comment: It'd be `import * as ko from 'knockout';`